# button click on a certain button, but the class names are the same

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've been trying to click on the open button but there a bunch of "opens" on the page. I tried using the xpath because there was a little difference but it still isnt clicking it once I get to that page this is what I have so far need some help please.

This is the code:

[image: code]

This is the error message I keep getting:

[image: error message]

Comment: Code is in image format..

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that you put the codes in text format instead of image so better readability.

I noticed that the issue you are facing is likely due to typo.

`//*[@id='pack-container'']/li[1]/div[2]/button[1]`

You have an additional apostrophe / single quote in the ID. It should be

`//*[@id='pack-container']/li[1]/div[2]/button[1]`

Comment: Thank you for the response, I cleared the extra quote and it still will not click this is the code now.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
"//*[@id='pack-container']/li[1]/div[2]/button[1]").click()
```

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='pack-container']/li[1]/div[2]/button[1]"}
(Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)

Comment: I figured out i had to add a time.sleep()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).